# If one constant in $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...c_nv_n=0$ does not equal zero, does that imply the zero vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, vectors

The definition for linear dependence between vectors is that:

$$c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...c_nv_n=0$$

Where at least one of the constants does not equal zero.

But why woould this hold true if only one of the constants did not equal zero?

If we assumed that every constant apart from $c_1$ equals zero, that would mean that:

$$c_2v_2+...c_nv_n=-c_1v_1$$

$$=>0=-c_1v_1$$

....Which pretty much tells us that $v_1$ has to be the zero vector, and that $v_1$ always has to be the zero vector, no matter the number of elements in the vectors. This tells us a vector is linearly dependant on one or more vectors when at least *two* of the constants in $c_1v_1+c_2v_2+...c_nv_n=0$ do not equal zero, whenever we're not dealing with the zero vector.

Is this the correct interpretation?

Comment: if $v_1$ is the zero vector, then the vectors are linearly dependent, no matter what the other $v_i$ are

Comment: Well yes, but is the interpretation correct? That if only one constant doesn't equal zero we must be working with the zero vector?

Comment: Yes, if exactly one of the constants is nonzero, the corresponding vector must be $0$.